# Newlines when setting a variable using echo

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I'm trying to use `\n` to output two seperate lines using echo and store that in a variable:

```
VAR=$( echo -e "foo\nbar" )
```

But the output I get is:

```
$ echo $VAR
foo bar
```

It works fine by itself:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar"
foo
bar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `$VAR` in double quotes:

```
echo "$VAR"
```

Otherwise, [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) occurs. This means that "foo" and "bar" are treated as two separate arguments to `echo` and the newline between them is lost.

You can use `set -x` to enable debug mode and see what happens:

```
$ set -x
$ echo $VAR
+ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo "$VAR"
+ echo 'foo
bar'
foo
bar
```

Comment: Interesting...so setting the variable with `echo` doesn't really add the newline to the variable. This is a tough one because I need to reference the variable elsewhere without `echo` and would like two separate lines of output

Comment: The newline **is** in the variable but the contents of a variable are split on whitespace characters when you don't wrap them in quotes.